# Magento inline translation not working, red dots are there but no book icon to change

Tags: magento

i have a problem with magento and the inline translation. 
If I turn on the inline translation I see the red dotted box around the text but there is no option anymore to click on the book icon and then do the translation.

Anybody had this before?

This is the link where you can see the issue

[link](http://b2b.digirails.com/b2bde/)

Comment: Are you 100% sure you haven't turned on template path hints instead of inline translation?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced identical issues. To fix it, I copied the `js` dir from the `1.7.0.2` install pack, and it now works.

That said, I'm not sure if this will inadvertently bring up any other issues.

Comment: Ok that helps a little bit :-) Now I see the icon but clicking it doesn't help. Maybe it's my template. I will do some testing with the default template. THanks for the help

Comment: this doesn't help. It'd be great if someone know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem come from z-index value, i found a css config of my theme which overlaps the book icon with another div with a z-index value higher than the inline translation.

Comment: Can you document some relevant CSS code that shows this resolution?